# Realizar agendamento de tarefas via PHP no windows

Tags: php, windows, iis

Preciso realizar o agendamento do envio de um email dinamicamente em um servidor windows rodando o IIS. tenho o seguinte código em PHP:

```
    class AgendarTarefaWindow{

       public function agendar($nome, $data, $tarefa){
           $array = explode(' ',$data);

           $comando = 'SCHTASKS /Create /SC ONCE /TN '.$nome.' /TR "'.$tarefa.'" /ST '.$array[1].' /SD '.$array[0].' /F ';

           $dados = system($comando,$resultado);

           var_dump($dados, $resultado, $comando);
        }

        public function excluirAgendamento($tarefa){
           exec('schtasks /Delete /TN '.$tarefa.' /F');
        }
    }  

    $agenda = new AgendarTarefaWindow();  

    $agenda->agendar('ncccTeste', date('d/m/Y H:i:s',strtotime( "+2 minute",strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')))), 'php -f  C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ClickFood\obj.php');
```

Se chamo ele via linha de comando: **php -f  enderecoArquivo** ele funciona perfeitamente. Já quando eu chamo ele pelo navegador o script simplesmente não funciona.

Se alguém souber o que pode ser fico muito grato.

O resultado do var_dump() e o seguinte:

```
   string(0) "" 
   int(-2147467259) 
   string(121) "SCHTASKS /Create /SC ONCE /TN ncccTeste /TR "php -f C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ClickFood\obj.php" /ST 14:30:00 /SD 23/07/2015 /F "
```

Comment: Quando você utiliza o navegador, qual o resultado do comando `var_dump()`? Edite sua pergunte e coloque esses valores por favor.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

Um *script* mais simples executa? Se nada em PHP executa, o IIS não está configurado para executar PHP. E aí, já que a pergunta não dá detalhes, só posso fazer este diagnóstico e lhe indicar que deve [configurar](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php) o [IIS](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-and-configure-php).

Se só este *script* não está funcionando, pode ser um problema de privilégio. Dê permissão para acessar o *script* de forma privilegiada em que todos os *scripts* secundários chamados aí possam ser executados.

Eu não faria isto, isto pode ser uma brecha de segurança. Eu deixaria para isto ser executado pelo servidor de forma protegida. Ou seja, se precisa de acesso privilegiado, não deixe o acesso ser feito externamente. Se precisa de acesso externo, não faça nada privilegiado.

Esta linha é o paraíso do *hackers*: `$dados = system($comando,$resultado);`

Comment: A questão  e que quem sabe quando o email tem quer ser envia e aplicação isso apos uma dada ação do usuário. Logo quem agenda tarefa poderia ser agenda para qualquer momento em qualquer instante que aplicação esteja rodando. não vejo como a tarefa ser agendada por outro que não fosse aplicação (mesmo sendo um brecha de segurança), e claro que eu não necessito usar a função system, por exemplo hj o agendamento funciona através de uma aplicação daemon, que imagino eu que seja mais segura por que não da acesso externo ao sistema mas e menos confiável.

Comment: Olha, seu texto está um pouco estranho, não sei se entendi. Mas te digo uma coisa, nenhum requisito vale escancarar a segurança do servidor.

Comment: Desculpa o texto não sou muito bom para escrever.

A questão e que hoje ele funciona com uma aplicação daemon em php e a comunicação e feita com aplicação real através de um arquivo.

A outra possibilidade e SCHTASKS através que eu não consegui fazer funcionar provavelmente por causa da questão de permissão e era minha primeira ideia. Só que como não consegui fazer funcionar post a pergunta para ver o que estou fazendo de errado para que ele não funcione.

Comment: Aqui só uma pergunta o que você faria nessa questão manteria a aplicação da daemon ou você arrumaria outra solução? 
Aqui desde já muito obrigado pela sua resposta ela já me ajudou.